# Is it possible to rename Azure Synapse SQL Pool?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am using an Azure SQL Database for our team's reporting and the data size right now is too big to handle by a single data (at least I think so, it has 2 fact tables with around 100m rows in each table).

The Azure SQL Database is named "operation-db" and the Synapse is named "operation-synapse".

I want to make the transition for my team become as smooth as possible. So I'm planning to copy all the tables, views, stored procedure and user-defined function over to Synapse.

Once I'm done with that, is there a way to rename "operation-synapse" to "operation-db" so the team doesn't have to go to their code base to change the name of the db?

Thanks!

Comment: Any other way, I have a question, what's your Azure SQL database price tier? Can scale up to higher price tier meet you request?

Comment: it's running on a 80 vCores already

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to rename a SQL Pool via SQL Server Management Studio and you will receive the following error:

> ALTER DATABASE NAME statement is not supported in a Synapse workspace.
> To update the name of a SQL pool, use the Azure Synapse Portal or the
> Synapse REST API.  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 49978)

The [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/sqlpools/rename) however does list a `move` method to change names:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/{workspaceName}/sqlPools/{sqlPoolName}/move?api-version=2019-06-01-preview
```

I couldn't get it to work though.  YMMV.  Not renaming your db shouldn't be a big deal though.  Your team should feel comfortable with changing connection strings etc and it will help them understand they are moving to a different product (Synapse) with different characteristics.

Before you move to Synapse however, have you look at Clustered Columnstore indexes in Azure SQL DB?  They are default type of index in a SQL Pool database but are also available in SQL DB.  They *can* compress your data 5-10x so it might end up not that big at all.  Columnstore is great for aggregate queries but less so for point lookups so have a think about your workload before you migrate.

Comment: I'm looking into [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/rename-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7). Looks like it's possible. To be honest, I'm just so fed up with the solutions from Microsoft and their documents are all over the place. Some features are in the Docs, some are in the blogs, there isn't any focus to provide a good source of references for users...I'm just gonna migrate things to Synapse and just gonna get it over with. Don't have time to look into a bunch of this and that anymore.

Comment: @wBlob anyway thanks a lot for your recommendations.

Comment: sorry, [this is the article I meant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/sqlpools/rename)

Comment: Ok, interesting there’s something in the API but not the GUI.  I’ll try it out later, NB it’s in preview.

Answer (score 1):

100 million rows is not big enough for synapse. Cci data in each shard will only have 1 row group (1mil rows).
Consider using partitioning or CCI in your sql db itself.
Also what's your usage pattern? If you are doing point lookups and updates clustered indexes will perform better.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of dedicated SQL Pools. The older standalone or "Classic DW", can be renamed using the ALTER DATABASE  MODIFY NAME  command. The second type, Dedicated SQL Pools that are part of a Synapse Workspace, can only be named at the time of creation or when creating a new database from a restore point. Renaming this type of DSP is not supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/sql-pools/rename?tabs=HTTP

Limitations outlined in the documentation:

MODIFY NAME = new_database_name
Renames the database with the name specified as new_database_name.
The 'MODIFY NAME' option has some support limitations in Azure Synapse:

- •    Unsupported with Azure Synapse serverless pools
- •    Unsupported with dedicated SQL pools created in your Azure Synapse
  Workspace
- •    Supported with dedicated SQL pools (formerly SQL DW) created via
  the Azure portal

These same limitations apply to the REST API here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/sql-pools/rename?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0

The actual limitation is in the main REST document here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-manage-compute-rest-api

The REST APIs that are described in this article are for standalone dedicated SQL pools (formerly SQL DW) and are not applicable to a dedicated SQL pool in an Azure Synapse Analytics workspace. For information about REST APIs to use specifically for an Azure Synapse Analytics workspace, see Azure Synapse Analytics workspace REST API.

I hope that this helps to clarify the options for renaming a dedicated SQL pool. Changing the name of a dedicated SQL pool that is created as part of a Synapse Analytics workspace is unsupported. Renaming is only supported for dedicated SQL pools that were created as stand-alone Azure Data Warehouse instances.

Answer (score -1):

You can rename a Synapse database easily using the SSMS GUI. (I've just tried this on v18.8).

Just click once on the database name in the Object Explorer to select it, then press the F2 key to rename it.

The Synapse service must be running (i.e. not paused) for the rename to work.

Comment: this is not supported anymore.

Comment: Hi Adrien -- thanks for the downvote, --- I just tested this again today 2022-07-08 -- and it still works. I'm sorry if it didn't work for you, but it definitely still works.

Answer (score -1):

You can rename Synapse database using T-SQL. The command is as follows:

```
ALTER DATABASE [OldSynapseDBName]
MODIFY NAME = [NewSynapseDBName]
```

**Note** you need to be connected to/issue the command from the **master** database otherwise it will not work.

The command takes can 30 seconds on 100GB DB and there are some caveats such as DB must not be used during operation.

Comment: How this REST API works wrt rename of Synapse dedicated SQL pool? 
What should be the target resource ID in request body?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/sql-pools/rename

Comment: this is not supported anymore.