# Is there any way to rename an azure synapse serverless SQL pool database?

Tags: azure-synapse

I want to align the database names in my dev and prod synapse workspaces' serverless SQL pools. How can I rename these databases?

If I can't renmame, maybe I could copy the DB? Not seeing that in the docs, either...

When I run:

`alter database DevLake MODIFY name = DataTeam;`

I get:

"MODIFY NAME is not supported for ALTER DATABASE"

I've also tried sp_renamedb as well as using the SSMS GUI. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to rename m database which is in synapse serverless pool with below code:

```
alter  database azuresb modify  name= syndb
```

I got below error.

[image]

I found that as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/255494/synapse-serverless-database)

> It is not possible to rename database in synapse serverless pool.

along with that as per [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest&preserve-view=true&tabs=sqlpool#modify-name--new_database_name-2) `MODIFY NAME = newDatabaseName` option has limitations in Azure Synapse:

> - It is not supported with Azure Synapse serverless pools.
> - It is not supported with SQL dedicated pools created in your Azure Synapse Workspace.
> - It is supported with dedicated SQL pools (formerly SQL DW) created via the Azure portal.

Comment: Yeah - that's what I saw as well. Was hoping for a workaround. Thanks for confirming. Hope to see this capability in the future.

Comment: I wonder if we might be able copy the DB into a new one with different name?

Comment: You can use Rest API to rename database check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64014302/is-it-possible-to-rename-azure-synapse-sql-pool) once.